# cakephp save select multi-value of foreign key list

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-2.0

Iam using Cakephp with select2 setup allover with foreign keys and associations.
But now...
I need to save a field where the user can select one or more options.
The field is a foreign key created as such:

```
$partQuarantaineStatuses = $this->Part->PartQuarantaineStatus->find('list');
```

in de debugger I see the key-value pairs.
When user saves to database it continues but the value in the mysql field shows

> 0

though the debugger shows:

> $request->data(array)
>           >Part (array)
>                 >part_quarantaine_status_id["2","3","4"]

in the controller:

```
 $this->request->data['Part']['part_quarantaine_status_id'] = json_encode($this->request->data['Part']['part_quarantaine_status_id']);
        }

        if( $this->Part->saveAll($this->request->data))
```

I found a multi-value field the best option, so I really want to put this in one single field.

How do I save the multi-value?

Comment: Right, nothing to do with json, weird that it did'nt work the first time. the code in my controller should have been:  $this->request->data['Part']['part_quarantaine_status_id'] = implode('; ',$this->request->data['Part']['part_quarantaine_status_id']);